# Local copy of ASP.NET MVC beta quickstarts?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I just downloaded the ASP.NET MVC beta and wanted to walk through the quickstarts locally.  It didn't look like they were installed with the beta installer, and I didn't see an independent download link for them.  Is there a place I can find these to save and use locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently they are only available online here: http://quickstarts.asp.net/previews/mvc/